# How to change selected region with original color?

Tags: android

I have 1 Bitmap image and i had converted that image into grayscale. My problem is I have to change the selected region of image with the original color. For that i am using getPixel() and setPixel() function on canvas in onDraw() method. I got the region also using onTouch method but i am unable to save the bitmap.

Please Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to store a bitmap on android (e.g. as a png):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height...);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/some/place/bla.png"));
target.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```